# Paste values only into a new sheet from a master sheet using importrange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a button that makes a copy of the master sheet into an archive folder. I've got that working, but it requires me to 'Allow Access' to several external sheets, which ruins all the formulas in the archived version (as it's trying to pull from backend sheets that are waiting for the `importrange` to be allowed).

Now, I'm looking to hard copy the values only from the master sheet into the archived version, so they are static values as they were at the time of creation. However, I'm getting 'Exception: Range not found' error when I try to archive, and the `importrange` formula remains in the archived sheet version.

Here's my code:

```
function archiveSheet () {
  
  var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Have you fully completed the RTU?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
 
if(confirm=='no'){Logger.log('The user clicked "NO."')};
if(confirm=='yes'){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var RTUDate = ss.getRange('Backend!O9').getValue();
Logger.log(RTUDate)

var RTUTime = ss.getRange('Backend!O12').getValue();
Logger.log(RTUTime)

// generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as Month Date, Year
//GMT+10 selected as server is in USA
//E.g. February 17, 2021 10:00:00 -0800
//https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(RTUDate,"GMT+20", "MMMM dd, yyyy");

//formats time
var formattedTime = Utilities.formatDate(RTUTime,"GMT+20","HH:mm");

// gets the name of the original file and appends a space " " followed by the timestamp stored in formattedDate
var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " " + formattedDate + " " + formattedTime;

// gets the destination folder by their ID
var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("MyDriveIDHere");

// gets the current Google Sheet file
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());

// makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
var newFile=file.makeCopy(name, destination);





// here is where the error occurs (I think):

var source_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Codex');
var target_sheet_ID = SpreadsheetApp.OpenByID(newFile.getID());
var target_sheet = target_sheet_ID.getSheetByName('Codex');
source_sheet.getRange('Codex!A2:O').copyTo(target_sheet_ID.getRange('Codex!A2:O'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already selected the sheet Codex you should only put the A1 notation of the ranges. Delete 'Codex!' and see if it works. Copying and pasting has its limitations between different spreadsheets. You may try replacing that last line with:

```
var values = source_sheet.getRange('A2:O').getValues()
target_sheet_ID.getRange('A2:O').setValues(values)
```